# Loading classes that extends other with SystemJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, systemjs

I have two classes in my Angular2 app, where one extends the other, like so, 
The first in the file course.ts (js when loaded)

```
export class Course {
    id:string;
}
```

And the second in schoolCourse.ts (js when loaded)

```
import {Course} from "./course";
export class SchoolCourse extends Course {
    code:string;
}
```

To load the app in the browser the following code for SystemJs

```
 <script>
  System.config({
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('app/app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

When I load the app with the SchoolCourse class as an extended class, I get the error

> Class extends value undefined is not a function or null

emitted from angular2-polyfills.js

Expanding and looking at the stacktrace it is from

> Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/app/boot.js
>       at execute (http://localhost:3000/app/courses/schoolCourse.js:15:48)

That line referenced is the line that in js says that SchoolCourse extends Course.

To me this sounds like a problem loading Course before the SchoolCourse class, but I could be so totally of, and I am no wiz as SystemJs.

Anyone know how I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Does your `SchoolCourse` class `import` the `Course` class?

```
import {Course} from './path/to/course';

export class SchoolCourse extends Course {
    code: string;
}
```

The `import` line should indicate to SystemJS that `Course` must be loaded before `SchoolCourse`.

Another thing to check - in your browser's development tools, open up the Network tab and observe the traffic as your app loads.  Does a call to `schoolCourse.js` get made before the call to `course.js`?

Comment: Yeah, I already had the import, just missed to copy it when I copied a part of my class since the other details isn't important. As for the network tab, yeah, the course class is loaded long before the SchoolCourse class

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a problem that wasn't SystemJs at all, or anything more than stupidity I think, the dev team didn't observe the user o the same function name in the Course class and the SchoolCourse class. When that was fixed everything worked fine.

So, diffuse error, stupid mistake. At least maybe this helps someone else having a bad day...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import the Course class before using to extend the SchoolCourse one:

```
import {Course} from './course';

export class SchoolCourse extends Course {
  (...)
}
```

What probably disturbes you in the message is that a function is expected. In fact whereas there is a class keyword in TypeScript and ES6, classes correspond under the hood to JavaScript constructor functions. That's why a function is expected at runtime to extend.

In you don't import, the corresponding module isn't loaded (you don't see a call for http://localhost:3000/app/courses/course.js in the Network tab of devtools in your browser) and Course remains undefined.

Comment: Yeah, I already had the import, just missed to copy it when I copied a part of my class since the other details isn't important. As for the network tab, yeah, the course class is loaded long before the SchoolCourse class

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "just missed to copy it when I copied à part of my class" ;-) but definitely interested in more details! Perhaps you could put details in your question or provide yourself an answer... This could be useful! Thanks!

Comment: Okay I understand! You didn't forget the export keyword for the Course class... Just a guess.